# Laravel - Where do i need to place my sum()

Tags: laravel, sum

This variable can shows me data about any **invoice** in relation with **sub_account** in relation with **account**.

I have data in invoice which is **amount** that i can display correctly. But i need to display the sum of all the **amounts** that have the same sub_account. 
**Problem** it aprears 2 time for each invoice like in the image below.

This is my code:
view:

```
 @foreach($invoices as $invoice)
    @foreach($invoice->subaccount as $sub_accounts)
       <tr>
              @foreach($sub_accounts->subaccountinvoice as $sub_account)
                  <td scope="row">{{$sub_account->sum('amount')}}</td>
               @endforeach
        </tr>                   
    @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

In controller :

```
 $invoices = Account::with(['subaccount.subaccountinvoice])->where('id',$id)->get();
```

Thank you.

[2 times the sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU4n1.png)

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the $sum variable over to your view file.

```
return view('yourView')->with(['sumAmount' => $sum]);
```

And then echo out the variable $sumAmount in your view file:

```
{{$sumAmount}}
```

Comment: Hello @polaris, it shows me the sum which is 5000. but 2 time, for every invoice that got the same sub_account.  I uploaded a picture  to see, please check my eddited post

Comment: @yassinej I'm not quite understanding what you're saying, could you be a little more clear?

Comment: Yes,  please check my eddited post, i added an image of my table after edditing my code.  the sum =5000. But it apprears two times in the table.

Comment: @yassinej I edited my post, hopefully it works, it's hard for me to visualize what's going on without all of the code.

Comment: @yassinej can you post the entire blade file and controller?

Comment: yes i eddited my post. actualy that all my blade and controller

Answer (score 0):

pass the sum and the invoice model with compact

Controller

```
$invoices = Account::with(['subaccount' => function($query)
{$query->with('subaccountinvoice')->get();}])->where('id',$id)->get();

$sum=Invoice::sum('amount');

return view('yourView', compact('invoices', 'sum'));
```

view

```
<span>{{$sum}}</span>
```

Comment: I have the same problem.. the sum apprears 2 tiimes for each invoice